# Calculate 2d position of a point, at a fixed offset off the start of a vector

Tags: geometry

I'm creating piece of software that does some basic drawing, but I'm not that well skilled in geometry :-)

I have two inputs, Position A, position B and a distance D. And i'm looking for the position of the point with offset D from A at an angle of 90 degrees from the vector:

[image: Example of question]

So, the question is: how to calculate the point in the bottom right? 
Note: ofcource, is should work in any X,Y direction and in both positive and negative coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the basis of your input there will be two solutions to this (assuming the vectors are in a 2D plane).

If the points are A is ($x_a$, $y_a$), B is ($x_b$, $y_b$) and D is ($x_d$, $y_d$) then the direction vectors AB and AD are at right angles so their dot-product is zero. i.e. ($x_b$ - $x_a$).($x_d$ - $x_a$) + ($y_b$ - $y_a$).($y_d$ - $y_a$) = 0. Plug in the numbers and you get a linear relation in $x_d$ and $y_d$ (unless A = B which you should check for first), and you can then express  $y_d$ in terms of $x_d$ and substitue in the length equation described below.

Now set the length of AD by resolving AD.AD (the dot-product) = $L^2$ where L is the required length.